# Display view when DatePicker is selected

Tags: ios, view, datepicker

I want the user select date using DatePicker and display result in new view.
For example if the user selects 1995 or 2000 from DatePicker and when hits the button application will display result in new view. Any help or tutorial will help. Thank's!

Answer (score 2):

**UIDatePicker** object sends an action message when a user finishes rotating one of the wheels to change the date or time; the associated control event is `UIControlEventValueChanged`.So make function be called after value is changed (user finish selecting date)

```
UIDatePicker *picker = //alloc init
[picker addTarget:self action:@selector(valueChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged]


 -(void)valueChanged:(UIDatePicker *)sender{
    //change here you view
  }
```

Comment: Hossam.thank's for your answer any tutorial it will be helpful